# Adding other currency format to AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to add other currency formats like euro to currency filter in AngularJS ?

```
<div ng-app>
    <p>
        <label>Enter Cost</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="cost" />
    </p>

    <p> {{ cost | currency }} </p>
</div>
```

Comment: you can create your own filters in angular js.

Comment: the second parameter of the filter is the string representing the symbol to use.  i.e. `{{cost | currency : "€" }}`

Comment: Did you try looking this up? It's written pretty blatantly in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could choose to create a custom filter for your currency of choice. However according to [Angulars Documentation on the Currency Filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/currency) that you can simply provide the symbol, currency abbreviation, and decimal place formatters for your currency .

In HTML Template Binding :

```
{{ currency_expression | currency : symbol : fractionSize}}
```

In JavaScript :

```
$filter('currency')(amount, symbol, fractionSize)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass in `html entities` after `currency:`. Here are a couple examples.

```
Item Price<span style="font-weight:bold;">{{price | currency:"&euro;"}}</span>
Item Price<span style="font-weight:bold;">{{price | currency:"&yen;"}}</span>
```

From the documentation, the format for this filter is

> {{ currency_expression | currency : symbol : fractionSize}}

Answer (score 1):

```
<div ng-app>
    <p>
        <label>Enter Cost</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="cost" />
    </p>
    <!-- Change USD$ to the currency symbol you want -->
    <p> {{cost| currency:"USD$"}} </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As described in the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/currency), simply add the currency symbol you want after the filter.

`<p> {{ cost | currency : '€' }} </p>`

Answer (score 1):

```
// Setup the filter
app.filter('customCurrency', function() { 

  // Create the return function and set the required parameter name to **input**
  // setup optional parameters for the currency symbol and location (left or right of the amount)
  return function(input, symbol, place) {

    // Ensure that we are working with a number
    if(isNaN(input)) {
      return input;
    } else {

      // Check if optional parameters are passed, if not, use the defaults
      var symbol = symbol || '$';
      var place = place === undefined ? true : place;

      // Perform the operation to set the symbol in the right location
      if( place === true) {
        return symbol + input;
      } else {
        return input + symbol;
      }

    }
  }
```

Then pass whatever currency you need.

```
<ul class="list">
     <li>{{example1 | customCurrency}} - Default</li>
     <li>{{example1 | customCurrency:'€'}} - Custom Symbol</li>
     <li>{{example1 | customCurrency:'€':false}} - Custom Symbol and Custom Location</li>
</ul>
```